# Varios input con un mismo name

Tags: html

Quiero poner varios input con el mismo name, pero en cuanto lo intento funciona únicamente el primero. Lo que quiero es cambiar de color un texto infinitamente, y eso lo tengo, pero solo funciona en el primer input, como he dicho anteriormente.
Quería saber si se puede hacer de alguna manera porque soy un principiante y me hacia ilusión. Y si no es mucha molestia, me gustaría no tener que utilizar css, php o algo del estilo, pero javascript lo admito(yo prefiero que sea sin css o php pero si es la única manera no me importa).

Este es el texto que quiero arreglar:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script> 
            var coloresIntermedios = ['#FF0000','#FF1000'];
            var color = 0;

            function otroColor() { 
                document.forms[0].cdc.style.color = coloresIntermedios[color++ % coloresIntermedios.length]; 
            } 
        </script> 

        <title>Ejemplo</title> 
    </head> 
    <body background="C:\Users\Public\Paginas WEB\1.jpg" onload="setInterval('otroColor()', 100)"> 
        <center> 
            <p>
                <form>
                    <input id="tc" disabled type="submit" type="text" name="cdc" value="Colores 1" />
                </form> 
            <p>
                <form>
                    <input id="tc" disabled type="submit" type="text" name="cdc" value="Colores 2" />
                </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Un input no debe tener el mismo name de otro, así como un elemento no debe tener el mismo id de otro

Comment: CSS + clases, javascript es impráctico de mantener, y php por su cuenta propia no lo hace

Comment: @CamiloVasquez para los nombres si se puede, si no cómo funcionaría un grupo de radio buttons?

Comment: @Lixus El grupo de radio buttons funciona solo dejando activo **uno** de su grupo no todos al tiempo, lo mismo pasa si repites un id javascript solo interactua con el primero que encuentre no con todos , hay que usar buenas prácticas en el código

Comment: @CamiloVasquez tendria que usar css  para que funcionase?

Comment: tengo entendido que css es una programacion quelee en cascada. con css se podria hacer entonces, verdad

Comment: Para la manipulación de varios input desde javascript no es necesario que tengan el mismo nombre, lo puede hacer agregando un nombre especifico de clase a estos input, algo así: `<input type="text" id="input1" class="myclass">` <input type="text" id="input2" class="myclass">` y en su javascript utilizando jquery puede hacer algo así: `$('.myclass').on('click', function() {});` suponiendo que lo que quieres hacer es manipular los eventos click de todos los input que contengan la classe `myclass`

Comment: @Ale muchas gracias pero necesito que  los objetos que esten en myclass tengan el name cdc, y no se como hacer eso

Comment: @user63361 en este caso le recomiendo que antes de esto pueda ver o leer tutoriales, ya sea de javascript o de jquery porque para lo que quiere es fundamental tener esas bases

Comment: muchas gracias intentare eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu código veo que estabas muy cerca de lograr tu objetivo, tu error era que siempre estabas seleccionando el `form[0]` osea siempre estabas seleccionando el primer `form` ignorando el segundo, por lo cual lo único que debes hacer es recorrer todos los `form` existentes, además te arregle varios errores que tenias en cuanto a apertura y cierre de etiquetas.

```js
var coloresIntermedios = ['#FF0000','#333333'];

function otroColor() { 
    for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++){
        document.forms[i].cdc.style.color = coloresIntermedios[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="setInterval('otroColor()', 100)">
<center>
    <p>
        <form>
            <input id="tc" disabled type="submit" name="cdc" value="Colores 1" />
        </form> 
    </p>

    <p>
        <form>
            <input id="tc" disabled type="submit" name="cdc" value="Colores 2" />
        </form> 
    </p>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Comment: de verdad del alma

Comment: se que es una tonteria pero gracias

Comment: no sabes los dias que estado preguntandome como hacer esto, ademas de que cuando he preguntado habia perdido la esperanza de que se pudiera hacer algo

Comment: pero ahora lo he conseguido gracias a ti

Comment: aunque tambien he de pedir las gracias a los que han intentado ayudarme aunque no lo hayan conseguido

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, te recuerdo que los comentarios son única y exclusivamente para solicitar información detallada o hacer una petición respecto a una pregunta/respuesta, la mejor manera de dar las gracias a una respuesta que te ha servido es marcarla como aceptada y como respuesta útil, te invito a que te hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español!